# Role of export() without an argument in a namespace file

Tags: r, package

I found this in the NAMESPACE file for a package:

```
export()
```

When I look at reference docs for `export()`, all the examples I find use an argument, e.g., `export(myFunc)`, and I cannot locate an exact man page for `export()`. What will the above line do?

Comment: Could you link to where you found this?!

Comment: @NelsonGon [Here](https://github.com/nickmckay/nuspectral/blob/master/NAMESPACE) is the package I was looking at. Note that it does throw namespace errors on import to R (3.6). (I am not updating the question as the content linked is unstable.)

Comment: Do you own this package? I think the package fails to build due to what seems to be issues with the use of `useDynLIb`.

Answer (score 0):

When documenting functions in a package, one will usually use the function `export` implying that the function that has been specified should be `exported` as part of the package.

The `NAMESPACE` holds information about functions `import`ed from other packages as well as those `export`ed from the package one is writing. Hence, under the `NAMESPACE` file, the `export(myFunc)` simply refers to a function that will be part of the package. It is nowadays normally not generated by hand and is done with `roxygen2`. **An empty `export()` might be a design error** because  as the manual [states](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.pdf):

> Exports are specified using the export directive in the NAMESPACE file. A directive of the form
>   export(f, g)
>   specifies that the variables f and g are to be exported. (Note that variable names may be
>   quoted, and reserved words and non-standard names such as [<-.fractions must be.)

For more intuition, look at the error that occurs when you try to use a function not `export`ed as part of a package.

```
stats::group_by
```

> Error: 'group_by' is not an exported object from 'namespace:stats'